# Runtime Exception during Pedestal Routing

Tags: clojure, pedestal

I'm using routes like so in my Pedestal webapp:

```clj
(def routes
  [[["/" ^:interceptors [(body-params/body-params)
                         middlewares/params
                         params/keyword-params
                         coerce-body content-neg-intc
                         session-interceptor
                         ensure-db-interceptor
                         datomic-conn-db-interceptor]
     {:get `home-page}]
    ;; other routes
```

This works fine. But I have a number of routes with common interceptors, so I'm trying to factor them out like so:

```clj
(def default-interceptors
  [(body-params/body-params)
   middlewares/params
   params/keyword-params
   coerce-body
   content-neg-intc
   session-interceptor
   ensure-db-interceptor
   datomic-conn-db-interceptor])

(def routes
    [[["/" ^:interceptors default-interceptors
       {:get `home-page}]
       ;; other routes...
```

When I navigate to this route, I get an exception:

*clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: java.lang.AssertionError in Interceptor :io.pedestal.http.route/router - Assert failed: Cannot expand '[#Interceptor{:name :io.pedestal.http.body-params/body-params} #function[io.pedestal.http.ring-middlewares/params] #Interceptor{:name :io.pedestal.http.params/keyword-params} {:name :service/coerce-body, :leave #function[service/fn--26867]} #Interceptor{:name :io.pedestal.http.content-negotiation/negotiate-content} #Interceptor{:name :io.pedestal.http.ring-middlewares/session} #Interceptor{:name :service/ensure-db-interceptor} #Interceptor{:name :service/datomic-conn-db-interceptor}]' as a route. **Expected a verb map or path string, but found a class clojure.lang.PersistentVector instead***

I'm not sure what's going wrong here. What is the correct way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i needed a type hint on the interceptors vector var

```clj
(def default-interceptors
  ^:interceptors [(body-params/body-params)
   middlewares/params
   params/keyword-params
   coerce-body
   content-neg-intc
   session-interceptor
   ensure-db-interceptor
   datomic-conn-db-interceptor])
```